# Resaltar una fila de un widget ttk TreeView al pasar el raton por encima?

Tags: python

¿Es posible resaltar una fila de un ttk TreeView al pasar el ratón por encima, en Python, al igual que lo hace el explorador de archivos de windows.
Un saludo

Comment: Si es posible. Sin embargo, no es una caracteristica que tenga el treeview. Eso significa que tendrás que crear tu propia función que haga eso.

Comment: Para habilitar los tags puedes usar esta respuesta en SO (sitio en ingles): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009674/12913664

Comment: Por que el voto de cierre? No veo esta pregunta como basada en opiniones.

Comment: No entendi tu comentario.